# SwiftUI `ViewModifier` detect if `content` has `opacity` 0

Tags: swiftui, viewmodifier

I'm trying to write a custom `ViewModifier` where my implementation needs to detect if the `content` it is modifying is visible or not. This is not an ordinary `ViewModifier` where it's irrelevant if the content is visible; the modifier is attempting to track visibility for the purpose of determining if the underlying content should be streamed via video capture.

(It's still confusing to me why Apple did not provide a `.visible(_ visibility: Visibility)` with `enum Visibility { case visible, case hidden, case collapsed }`, and instead encouraged using `.opacity(_:)` to conditionally hide views. But that's another story.)

In any case, while I can set the opacity with `.opacity(_:)`, I can't get the `content`s opacity. Note that `onAppear` is called, even for views with opacity set to 0.

```
struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .mymodifierimplemtation()
            .onAppear() {
                // Called even if content opacity is 0
                print("Appeared")
            }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: You cant detect the status of `content` but you can create your own logic in the `ViewModifier`. It won't be able to detect changes made outside of the `ViewModifier`.

Comment: Go to where you decide if opacity is set as 0 and do the action there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom modifier to set the view's opacity to 0 and use `EnvironmentValues` to track the visibility of this view in your `ViewModifier` using:

```
@Environment(\.visibility) var visibility
```

**Environment Key:**

```
struct VisibilityEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = Visibility.automatic
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var visibility: Visibility {
        get { 
            self[VisibilityEnvironmentKey.self]
        }
        set { 
            self[VisibilityEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue 
        }
    }
}
```

**Visibility Modifier:**

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func visible(_ visibility: Visibility) -> some View {
        Group {
            if visibility != .automatic {
                self
                    .opacity(visibility == .hidden ? 0: 1)
            }
        }.environment(\.visibility, visibility)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These sort of SwiftUI attributes are designed to be one-way: the visual interface is a value of state, rather than the other way around. And so in general, a view is visible or not based on some condition or property – and it is that property, or changes to that property, which you would generally rely on for other views or effects.

Is there anything in your state which would give you the information you need?